# Remove customer protocol handler from that was set using web browser

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I used the `Navigator.registerProtocolHandler()` method in the browser API to register a custom protocol handler.  It works very well, and it does what I expected.  However, does anyone know how to remove a custom protocol handler once set?

Comment: chrome://settings/handlers

you can do it in Firefox by going through preferences